# What is the core codes of Laravel Eloquent behind the ->save() method to choose create or edit a new record in database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I understand Laravel is checking the `object reference id` to check if the object existed, so the `save()` method will run the `edit` method to edit it. and if it's a new object, it will run the `create()` method.

but I can't find the codes behind it, in the Eloquent package.

I want the exact address of the file that includes these codes

from the blow codes I infer the above conclusion:

I wrote this code in Laravel:

```
$setting = new Setting;
$setting->name = 'name1';
$setting->save();

$setting->name = 'name2';
$setting->save();
```

after executing I see just `name2` in the database and it seems, after saving `name1` Laravel edit that and save `name2` in the database.

and after I execute this code:

```
$setting = new Setting;
$setting->name = 'name1';
$setting->save();
$setting = new Setting;
$setting->name = 'name2';
$setting->save();
```

and I saw both the records saved correctly, so I have `name1` and `name2`.

Comment: The `save()` method is available [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/213b58db3736ba99f856a5bbf030fa7084ec8aef/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L833).

Comment: Laravel actually checks `$model->wasRecentlyCreated` to see if insert or update is needed. The model `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` contains the code behind save if you want to know the spicifics , next to the docs ofc :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the code for Eloquent's `save()` method in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` on line 833 in Laravel 8.12.

The behaviour that you're observing is a characteristic of the Active Record pattern, which Laravel is based on. Each time you use `new` to create an Eloquent model, it's creating a object that will represent a row in your database. Within Eloquent's `save()` method, it will check to see if a record already exists, and if it does it will update it (code below).

```php
if ($this->exists) {
    $saved = $this->isDirty() ?
                $this->performUpdate($query) : true;
}
```

Your code is working as expected.